# Partly truncated and not truncated data

Tags: regression, censoring, truncated-normal-distribution

In some places 100 km races stop to count time if a certain time limit has been passed, for example 15 hours. It is difficult, respective, not possible  to distinguish which finisher or site was affected by the limit. If I want compare groups, for example, gender or nationality, how I have to cope with that? One idea I had was censoring finisher who passed 15 hours. Any better idea?
Thanks

Update 1: Clarification of the problem
Let's assume there are 5 races A,B,C,D and E with each of them have between 200 and 1000 finishers, various nationalities, age, and male and female. In A and B only the participants have been recorded who had equal or less than 15 hours. All other participants in A and B who had more than 15 hours were not recorded and we don't know how many there are. If I want to study the effect of gender, nationality and age with regression, for example male would be overestimate if there are much more male than female in A and B and much more female than male in C, D and E (the races without time limit).

Update 2: Example lm with TRUE, REAL,CUTTED
Update 3: Example with truncreg, stls(truncSP), crch

In the following I simulate data (TRUE), truncated it (REAL) and processed it removing all observation > 15 from REAL (CUTTED):

- With **TRUE** data (all participant, also the one who are discharged by the organisation, this is my gold standard)
- With **REAL** data (participants are removed from the dataset, truncated)
- With **CUTTED** data (trimmed, only participants with hours <= 15 are considered)

With this datasets I performed ols (lm, see code below):

- **TRUE/lm**
- **REAL/lm**
- **CUTTED/lm**

Using packages dedicated to truncated data, the following regression have been performed using the REAL dataset:

- **CUTTED/truncreg**
- **CUTTED/stls** (truncSP/stls)
- **CUTTED/trch**

**Results**:

- **TRUE/lm**  ................................. -0.973
- **REAL/lm**  .................................. -1.597
- **CUTTED/lm**............................. -0.216
- **CUTTED/truncreg**.................. -0.735
- **CUTTED/stls** (truncSP/stls)... -0.828
- **CUTTED/trch**..........................  -0.735

**REAL/lm** overestimated the true paramater $\beta$, **CUTTED/lm** underestimated as expected.
**CUTTED/truncreg** and **CUTTED/trch** give identical results and underestimated true parameter. Also CUTTED/stls underestimated true parameter but less than the other two. stls does not compute standard errors (se). se can be computed changing parameter `covar =  FALSE` to TRUE but performance is bad.

Code for simulating data and computing estimates:

```
library("ggplot2")

seed(1234)

# Let's assume an effet in gender (female need 1 hour more than male for 100 km)
beta <- 1
mean_male <- 15
n_f <- 1000
n_m <- 2000

# Simulates races
hours_male   <- rnorm(n_m, mean_male,1)
hours_female <- rnorm(n_f, mean_male + beta,1)
# Create "TRUE" data
df0 <- data.frame(gender = rep(c('m','f'), c(n_m,n_f))
                  , hours = c(hours_male, hours_female)
                  )

# But: in some races the organisations don't record time after 15 hours
#      -> participants with > 15 are removed/unknown/truncate

df0$remove <- 0
# There are more man who are affected by the organisations rule
df0$remove <- with(df0, ifelse(gender == 'm' & hours > 15 & runif(nrow(df0)) > 0.1, 1,remove))
df0$remove <- with(df0, ifelse(gender == 'f' & hours > 15 & runif(nrow(df0)) > 0.9, 1,remove))


# Truncate participants affected by rule (produce "REAL" data)
df1 <- subset(df0, remove == 0)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=hours)) +
       geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),binwidth=.5, colour="black", fill="white") +
       geom_density() +
       facet_grid(gender ~.)
```

[image]

```
# --- Regressions
library("truncSP")
library("truncreg")
library("crch")

# "TRUE/lm" data and lm
round(summary(lm(hours ~ gender, data=df0))$coef,3)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   15.997      0.031 509.274        0
genderm       -0.973      0.038 -25.294        0

# "REAL/lm" data and lm
round(summary(lm(hours ~ gender, data=df1))$coef,3)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   15.972       0.03 536.894        0
genderm       -1.597       0.04 -39.522        0

 # "CUTTED/lm" Only runs with hours <= 15 and lm
round(summary(lm(hours ~ gender, data=subset(df1, hours <= 15)))$coef,3)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   14.426      0.047 309.917        0
genderm       -0.216      0.050  -4.306        0

# "CUTTED/truncreg" Only runs with hours <= 15 and with truncreg
round(summary(truncreg(hours ~ gender
                       , data=subset(df1, hours <= 15)
                       , direction="right"
                       , point = 15
                       )
              )$coef,3)
            Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   15.727      0.257  61.200        0
genderm       -0.735      0.184  -4.002        0
sigma          0.986      0.061  16.114        0

# "CUTTED/stls" Only runs with hours <= 15 and with truncSP/stls
round(summary(stls(hours ~ gender
                       , data=subset(df1, hours <= 15)
                       , direction = "right"
                       , point = 15
                       , beta = "ml"
                       , covar =  FALSE
                       )
              )$coef,3)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   15.720         NA      NA       NA
genderm       -0.828         NA      NA       NA

# "CUTTED/trch" Only runs with hours <= 15 and with crch
round(summary(trch(hours ~ gender
                       , data=df1
                       , subset = (hours <= 15)
                       , right=15
                       )
              )$coef$location,3)
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   15.727      0.257  61.200        0
genderm       -0.735      0.184  -4.002        0
```

Comment: Is there anything about the problem that treating it as censored at 15 hours would fail to capture?

Comment: @Glen_b I'm not sure if I understand your question. To avoid bias due to uncontrollable limitation policy I want to censor (cut at 15 hours) or truncate (remove finisher if >15 hours) all finishers. What I miss using censoring or truncation is only that I can't compare the mean and distribution of all participant.

Comment: We seem to have a failure to communicate. *Censoring* and *truncation* have very particular, distinct meanings. Truncation would describe a situation where if someone didn't finish the race inside the time limit, *you would not even know that had been in the race*. [Censoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)) would describe those that had been observed for a known amount of time but you don't know how much longer they might have taken (it's a particular form of censoring). ... ctd

Comment: ctd so the question is then how to treat the censored observations. Generally speaking you shouldn't leave them out as if they weren't in it and you shouldn't include them as if they had finished at the censoring times ... but what you should do depends on what you're trying to do with the data. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Glen_b thanks. I see: censoring the finisher who had more than 15 hours makes no sense since they had been recorded (see update 1). So, better to use a rule and cut at 15 hours, that is, remove all finishers who had more than 15 hours. Than, doing regression I can do inference considering that only participant lower or equal 15 hours have been used for the analysis.

Comment: despite its appearance "censoring" (as a statistical term) is in effect an adjective (describing which observations were not observed all the way to some event and the manner in which that occurred) rather than a verb (censoring is not something you do to the *data*). Whether it makes sense to remove anybody is still unclear, but I expect that it doesn't. I would advise against removing people until you have a question that makes it clearer what you're trying to find out. Even after your edit, I still don't know what your dependent variable is. Is it also time to complete the race? ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... If you want to estimate a model for average completion times with covariates, you might be best with a parametric survival model. If you want to compare factors that influence completion times, doing anything to people who failed to finish (either by including them as if they finished or excluding them as if they didn't race) will mislead you, potentially very badly.

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for the confusion. The outcome is time for 100 km and the goal is to see, for example for gender, who is faster and how much faster (male or female). If there are more men who were discharged (not recorded) due to time limit given by the orgranisation, there will be bias. See my update 2. A survival model could be a good idea. I will try it.